# Validar con Ajax y php si el usuario existe en MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Estoy queriendo realizar un chequeo de si existe el usuario en la BD de MySQL. Pero al escribir en el input, en la consola me tira error 500, cosa que no entiendo.. porque la conexión con la BD me funciona perfecto en otras partes de la pagina.

Este es el código:

```
          $(document).ready(function()
          {    
          $("#usuario").keyup(function()
          {  
          var name = $(this).val(); 
                                        
          if(name.length > 3)
          {  
          $("#result").html('checking...');
                                        
                                    
          $.ajax({
                                            
          type : 'POST',
          url  : 'username-check.php',
          data : $(this).serialize(),
          success : function(data)
        {
          $("#result").html(data);
        }
        });
        return false;
                                        
        }
        else
        {
        $("#result").html('');
       }
       });
                                        
       });
```

el input:

```
 <input class="input_user" type='text' maxlength="15" name="usuario" id='usuario' 
 placeholder="USUARIO" required autocomplete='off' />
 <span id="result"></span>
```

El PHP que recibe el POST y consulta a MySQL:

```
include('conectar.php');

if($_POST) 
{
  $name = strip_tags($_POST['usuario']);
  
  $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Usuario FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario=:name");
  $stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$name));
  $count=$stmt->rowCount();

  
 if($count>0)
 {
  echo "<span style='color:brown;'>El usuario ya esta en uso</span>";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<span style='color:green;'>Disponible</span>";
  }
 }
```

La conexion con la BD:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "******";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

En el sitio, abajo del input, en donde me deberia dar el resultado me aparece el texto checking... pero voy a la consola y me dice:

> Request URL:
> https://servidor:puerto/Comedores%20Totales/Administrador/Admin/username-check.php
> Request Method:
> POST
> Status Code:
> 500 Internal Server Error

No le encuentro la vuelta, si alguien me podria ayudar.. agradecere!

Comment: Si miras el log (error.log) del apache, verás el error concreto que causa el problema.

Comment: es con IIS, genera log igualmente?

Comment: si, pero se llama diferente y está en %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles o en %SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR aunque depende de como esté configurado, mira este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/iis-where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs

Comment: 10.8.179.157, Domain\user, 12/1/2023, 9:29:33, W3SVC4, SERVIDOR, IP, 101, 874, 766, 500, 0, POST, /Comedores Totales/Administrador/Admin/username-check.php, -,

Comment: eso me dice el log..

Comment: En lugar de usar _serialize()_, ¿has probado enviar el dato como 'data': {usuario:usuario}  ? Si solo vas a comprobar el nombre de usuario no es necesario enviar todos los campos del formulario en la llamada AJAX, especialmente si lo haces con keyup().

Comment: Juan, recién estoy aprendiendo de js y ajax.. en data pongo data: {usuario:usuario}, pero al cambiar eso me dice: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Comment: Como el log no aclara nada (me extraña mucho, pero no conozco profundamente iis), solo queda depurar. Comenta todo el código de username-check.php y prueba a ver si da 500, si no, ve descomentando poco a poco a ver si lo encuentras, como sugerencia, usa print_r para mostrar lo que recibes desde POST o REQUEST.

Comment: Un error en mi comentario anterior. Lo que debes enviar es data: {usuario:name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de muchas vueltas, ya que no se mucho de JS, Ajax, Jquery, busque por internet.. y llegue a esto:

```
   function verificarUsuario(usuario){
   var parametros = {usuario:usuario};
   $.ajax({
   url:"validarUsuario.php",
   data:parametros,
   type:"post",
   beforeSend:function(){
                                                    
      $("#resultado").html("Validando usuario ... ");
   },
   success:function(respuesta){
   console.log(respuesta)
   if(respuesta =="El usuario ya existe"){
                                                        
      $("#resultado").html(respuesta).css("color", "red");
      $('#comedor').prop('disabled',true);
      $('#region').prop('disabled',true);
      $('#permisos').prop('disabled',true);
      $('#submit_3').prop('disabled',true);

     } else{
      $("#resultado").html("Habilitado").css("color", "green");
      $('#comedor').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#region').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#permisos').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#submit_3').prop('disabled',false);
     } 
   }
 });
}
```

esto lo envia a un PHP:

```
$val_user = array();
$query = "SELECT Usuario FROM usuarios";

$respuesta = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuesta ) )
{
array_push( $val_user, $row[ 0 ] );
}

//print_r($val_user);

if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){
    $respuesta="";
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    

    if(in_array($usuario, $val_user )) {
        $respuesta = "El usuario ya existe";
    } else {
        $respuesta = "no existe";
    }
    echo $respuesta;
}
```

Donde hago la consulta de la tabla en MySQL, meto los datos en un array y luego lo escrito en el input, que es enviado por POST, hace la comparación de si ese usuario existe en el array de MySQL.

Entonces recibo la respuesta en la consola, y lo imprimo la etiqueta

```
<input class="input_user" type='text' maxlength="15" name="usuario" 
 id='usuario' 
value="" placeholder="USUARIO" required autocomplete='off' 
onblur="verificarUsuario($('#usuario').val())"/>
                                                                            
<span id="resultado"></span>
```

Posiblemente haya mejores formas de hacerlo, pero este me funciono muy bien. Agradezco los comentarios y si se puede mejorar este código aun mas, recibiré los consejos!